# How can I create an array of Unicode characters in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, unicode

I am using Repl.it.

```
import array as arr

my_array = arr.array("u", [u"3", u"6", u"9", u"12"])
print(my_array)
print(type(my_array))
print(type(my_array[0]))
```

The above source code produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_array = arr.array("u", [u"3", u"6", u"9", u"12"])
TypeError: array item must be unicode character
```

Why the source code isn't working?

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, I am using Repl.it.

Comment: I mean your `sys.version`?

Answer (score 2):

Array type `"u"` corresponds to a **single** Unicode character. The initializer contains a two-character item `u"12"`. Perhaps you want something like:

```
arr.array("u", [u"3", u"6", u"9", u"1", u"2"])
```

Comment: It can also be initialized more simply as `my_array = arr.array('u','36912')`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes. I assumed OP has to use a list since it was in the question

Comment: It was just a general comment.  The OP may not know it is easier to type.